# codeigniter autocomplete select values after validation fail

Tags: php, codeigniter, dropdown

in codeigniter how to show the previous selected option values after validation fail in a form

controller

```
protected function getStateOption($state_id=0) {
        $stateOptions = '<option value="0">--Select State--</option>';
        $stateList = $this->state_model->getState();
        foreach ($stateList as $state) {
            if(!empty($state_id)){
                 $stateOptions .= '<option value="' . $state->id . '" '.(($state_id && $state_id==$state->id) ? ' selected' : '').'> ' . $state->name. ' </option>';
             }else{
                $stateOptions .= '<option value="'.$state->id.'">'.$state->name.'</option>';
             }
        }
        return $stateOptions;
    }
```

view

```
<div id="state_div" class="view span3">
       <select id="state" name="state" >
        <?php echo $stateOptionsList; ?>
        </select>
        <span style="color:red;"><?php echo form_error('state')?></span>
      </div>
```

after posting the data if the validation fails it is loding and not showing the previously selected values.

Comment: Would you already considered to use a `helper` to populate this `select`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you recovered `$state_id` with [`set_value()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#set_value) or [`set_select()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#set_select) before use it in `getStateOption()`, you should try `if($state_id != 0)` instead of `if(!empty($state_id))`. I think that `$state_id` will never be empty...

Anyway, in my opinion, is better to re-populate the `form` directly in the `VIEW`.